# How to get a collection of all latest attributes values from DynamoDB?

Tags: database, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I have a one table where I store all of the sensors data.
**Id** is a Partition key, **TimeEpoch** is a sort key.
Example table looks like this:

| Id | TimeEpoch | AirQuality | Temperature | WaterTemperature | LightLevel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b8a76d85-f1b1-4bec-abcf-c2bed2859285 | 1608208992 | 95 |  |  |  |
| 3a6930c2-752a-4103-b6c7-d15e9e66a522 | 1608208993 |  |  | 23.4 |  |
| cb44087d-77da-47ec-8264-faccc2a50b17 | 1608287992 |  | 5.6 |  |  |
| latest | 1608287992 | 95 | 5.6 | 23.4 | 1000 |

I need to get all the latest attributes values from the table.
For now I used additional Item with **Id** = **latest** where I'm storing all the latest values, but I know that this is a hacky way that requires sensor to put data in with new GUID as the **Id** and to the **Id = latest** at the same time.
The attributes are all known and it's possible that one sensor under one **Id** can store **AirQuality** and **Temperature** at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL databases like DynamoDB are a tricky thing, because they don't offer the same query "patterns" like traditional relational databases.

Therefore, you often need non-traditional solutions to valid challenges like the one you present.

My proposal for one such solution would be to use a DynamoDB feature called [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html).

In short, DynamoDB Streams will be triggered every time an item in your table is created, modified or removed. Streams will then send the new (and old) version of that item to a "receiver" you specify. Typically, that would be a Lambda function.

**The solution** I would propose is to use streams to send new items to a Lambda. This Lambda could then read the attributes of the item that are not empty and write them to whatever datastore you like. Could be another DynamoDB table, could be S3 or whatever else you like. Obviously, the Lambda would need to make sure to overwrite previous values etc, but the detailed business logic is then up to you.

**The upside** of this approach is, that you could have some form of up-to-date version of all of those values that you can always read without any complicated logic to find the latest value of each attribute. So reading would be simplified.

**The downside** is, that writing becomes a bit more complex. Not at least because you introduce more parts to your solution (DynamoDB Streams, Lambda, etc.). This also will increase your cost a bit, depending on how often your data changes. Since you seem to store sensor data that might be quite often. So keep in mind to check the cost. This solution will also introduce more delay. So if delay is an issue, it might not be for you.

At last I want to mention that it is recommend to only have at most two "receivers" of a tables stream. That means that for production I would recommend to only have a single receiver Lambda and then let that Lambda create an AWS EventBridge event (e.g. "item created", "item modified", "item removed"). This will allow you to have a lot more Lambdas etc. "listening" to such events and process them, mitigating the streams limitation. This is an event-driven solution then. As before, this will add delay.